# cleveref and cases packages clash

Tags: cleveref, cases

In the MWE below cleveref produces `section 1' instead of a reference to equation 2. What's the easiest fix? (other than using \eqref or (\ref))

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{cases}


\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\begin{numcases}{}
 a=b \\
 c=d. \label{c=d}
\end{numcases}

Cleveref produces a reference to the section: \cref{c=d} 

Regular ref produces a reference to the equation: \ref{c=d}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the use of `cases` and with much code copied from Thorsten Donig:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} % loading `mathtools` % loading `amsmath`
\usepackage{cleveref} % load this as very last package

\begin{document}    
    \section{Intro} 
    \begin{empheq}[left={=\empheqbiglbrace~}]{align}
    a&=b\\
    c&=d\label{eq:equation} 
    \end{empheq}
    Cleveref produces a reference to the section: \cref{eq:equation} 

    Regular ref produces a reference to the equation: \ref{eq:equation}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: The package `cases` isn't maintained (referring to uploads on CTAN) since 2002 and the problem with `cleveref` has been spotted already but not fixed. So maybe you should not use this package for your case.