# How do I make subnumcases work with cleveref?

Tags: incompatibility, cleveref, cases

The following code does not yield the correct references with cleveref, but it does work as desired with regular references.  What is the easiest solution?  (See also [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201437/cleveref-and-cases-packages-clash) which highlights a similar problem but the solution provided there doesn't help here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{}
 x=y, \label{eq:x=y}\\
 z=a  \label{eq:z=a}
\end{subnumcases}
Equations \cref{eq:x=y,eq:z=a}...  \cref{eq:x=y} doesn't work. But \ref{eq:x=y} works well.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know cases is not maintained and I shouldn't be using it, but I don't know of a ready alternative!

Comment: If this is just a cases with eq numbers, then empheq can do that as well. Don't know how it works with cleverref as I never use that package

Comment: It's cases with subequation numbers, so 1a, 1b, 1c.

Comment: Ah, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165685/subequations-and-array-in-braces can be used!  Problem solved.