# Cross-referencing equations in subnumcases environment

Tags: cleveref, cases

When trying to cross-reference one of the multi-case equations in the `subnumcases` environment with `cleveref`, only the equation number is shown and not the letter. **Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{y=}
   x^2 + 1, & $n = 1$ \label{eq:1}\\
   3x^2 + 2, & $n > 1$ \label{eq:2}
\end{subnumcases}

We first want to refer to equation 1a with \Cref{eq:1}.
Then to equation 1b with \Cref{eq:2}.

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The equation number 1a etc. is not transported into `\@currentlabel` which stores the reference value to the `.aux` file finally -- that's wrong with it

Comment: Possibly related: [cleveref and cases packages clash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201437/cleveref-and-cases-packages-clash)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty hack would be to take [the solution for the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201450/27717), and alter it in the following way: we define a new environment `mysubnumcases`, which contains `empheq`, but first we

1. save the old value of the `equation` counter to a new one,
2. reset the `equation` counter to zero,
3. alter the appearance of equation numbers by renewing `\theequation`,
4. have the `empheq` environment,
5. restore the value of the `equation` counter.

so we have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} % loading `mathtools` % loading `amsmath`
\usepackage{cleveref} % load this as very last package

\newcounter{case}
\newenvironment{mysubnumcases}{
    \begingroup
    \stepcounter{equation}
    \setcounter{case}{\theequation}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{case}\alph{equation}}
    \empheq[left={=\empheqbiglbrace~}]{align}
}{
    \endempheq
    \setcounter{equation}{\thecase}
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}    
    \section{Intro} 
    \begin{equation}
        A=B \label{eq1}
    \end{equation}
    Some text
    \begin{mysubnumcases}
        a&=b\label{eq2}\\
        c&=d\label{eq3}
    \end{mysubnumcases}
    Some text
    \begin{equation}
        A=B \label{eq4}
    \end{equation}
    Cleveref references: \cref{eq1} \cref{eq2} \cref{eq3} \cref{eq4}.
\end{document}
```

[image]