# \eqref and cases package

Tags: hyperref, cases

I want to use a custom tag for some equations, but I'm not being allowed to. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x=y\tag{custom1}\label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{numcases}{}
        x=y \tag{custom2}\label{eq:2}
    \end{numcases}
    Why can I do \eqref{eq:1}, but not \eqref{eq:2}?
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Naturally I'd like the second `\eqref` to display as (custom2).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201450/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis I have not understood the question :-) as usual :-)

Comment: This appears to be a bug @DonaldArsenau It looks like a timing issue with the `\tag` environment and when `\@currentlabel` gets defined. I'm not sure if the bug is also in amsmath or not.